# pymysql - is it possible to use a variable as a "Where" parameter?

Tags: python, pymysql

### This is my code:

def lookfor(var1, var2):

```
try:
    with connection().cursor() as cursor:
        sql = """SELECT * FROM servers WHERE %s = %s"""

        cursor.execute(sql, (var1, var2))
        result = cursor.fetchall()

        for x in result:
            print(x)
finally:
    connection().close()
```

lookfor("priority", "Important")

--

I get 0 results and no errors... :(

Please help, there must be a way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use string interpolation:

```
with connection().cursor() as cursor:
        sql = "SELECT * FROM servers WHERE " + str(var1) + " = " + str(var2)

        cursor.execute(sql)
        result = cursor.fetchall()
```

Comment: Thank you so muchhhhhh!!!!!!!!!

When I changed both variables it gave me the following error: 
pymysql.err.InternalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'P1' in 'where clause'")

I ended up doing this and it works. 

sql = "SELECT * FROM servers WHERE " + str(var1) + " = %s"

            cursor.execute(sql, var2)

Thank you again Ling Vu!

Comment: Then mark this as correct answer. Very apprechiate it :)